# reindex multi level index with missing categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, reindex

I have a dataframe with two indexes, *group* and *class*. I have a dictionary containing additional levels that need to be added in to both those indexes. Specifically I want to add E to the *group* index. And i want to ensure all g1, g2, and g3 are present in the *class* index, per *group* (so add g3 to group A, g1 to group B, g2 and g3 to group C, and g1 and g3 to group D and g1, g2 and g3 to group E. I want to fill where appropriate the total column with zeros

the original dataframe is here

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'group' : ['A','A','B','B','C','D'],
                        'class': ['g1','g2','g2','g3','g1','g2'],
                        'total' : [3,14,12,11,21,9]})
```

the dictionary (and mapped df) containing all required categories is here

```
dic = {'group':['A','B','C','D','E'],
       'class' : ['g1','g2','g3']}
```

and the expected output is here

```
expectedOutput = pd.DataFrame(data={'group' : ['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D','E','E','E'],
                        'class': ['g1','g2', 'g3','g1','g2', 'g3','g1','g2', 'g3','g1','g2', 'g3','g1','g2', 'g3'],
                        'total' : [3,14,0, 0,12,11,21,0,0,0,9,0, 0,0,0]})
```

I am having a trouble maintaining the duplicated values when reindexing, but I need to keep them all. Any advice is welcome, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution with `MultiIndex` - created from `dict` by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
dic = {'group':['A','B','C','D','E'],
       'class' : ['g1','g2','g3']}

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(dic.values(), names=dic)

df = df.set_index(list(dic)).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
   group class  total
0      A    g1      3
1      A    g2     14
2      A    g3      0
3      B    g1      0
4      B    g2     12
5      B    g3     11
6      C    g1     21
7      C    g2      0
8      C    g3      0
9      D    g1      0
10     D    g2      9
11     D    g3      0
12     E    g1      0
13     E    g2      0
14     E    g3      0
```

Or with left join by `DataFrame` created by `itertools.product`:

```
from  itertools import product

dicDf = pd.DataFrame(product(*dic.values()), columns=dic)

df = dicDf.merge(df, how='left').fillna({'total':0})
print (df)
   group class  total
0      A    g1    3.0
1      A    g2   14.0
2      A    g3    0.0
3      B    g1    0.0
4      B    g2   12.0
5      B    g3   11.0
6      C    g1   21.0
7      C    g2    0.0
8      C    g3    0.0
9      D    g1    0.0
10     D    g2    9.0
11     D    g3    0.0
12     E    g1    0.0
13     E    g2    0.0
14     E    g3    0.0
```

Comment: oh wow what a fast answer thank you! I can see as well my dicDf didnt actually work as its dropping items in 'group' where there is no items in 'class' to match the row level *i will update it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nice [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor) module and its [`complete`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) method:

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor as jn 
(df.complete({'group': list(df['group'].unique())+['D', 'E']}, 'class')
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
)
```

output:

```
   group class  total
0      A    g1      3
1      A    g2     14
2      A    g3      0
3      B    g1      0
4      B    g2     12
5      B    g3     11
6      C    g1     21
7      C    g2      0
8      C    g3      0
9      D    g1      0
10     D    g2      9
11     D    g3      0
12     E    g1      0
13     E    g2      0
14     E    g3      0
```

Comment: I think if you use `dic` as is, you still get the same result : ``df.complete(dic).fillna(0, downcast='infer')``

Comment: @sammywemmy there is an extra value to add (E). Btw, see, now I started to use pyjanitor ;)